# Set per-app language with adb shell?

Tags: settings, languages, oxygenos, android-13

I was looking forward to using per-app languages with Android 13.

However, my OnePlus 8T does not feature the necessary settings item for that on OxygenOS 13.

Is it possible to set a different language with an adb shell command?

`adb shell settings get global settings_app_locale_opt_in_enabled` returns `null`, so I'm not sure if it's even implemented at all.

Smartphone is rooted with Magisk.

Answer (score 1):

9R user here. my native lang is ua, but I mainly use en. wanted to set ua for one particular app and also was seeking for this option. it seems that oneplus turned it off

https://www.reddit.com/r/oneplus/comments/zfgoy5/just_updated_my_op9_pro_to_oxygenos_13_but_cant/

```
$ ~/w/own [255]> adb shell settings put global settings_app_locale_opt_in_enabled false

Exception occurred while executing 'put':
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.enforceWritePermission(SettingsProvider.java:2562)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1562)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.insertGlobalSetting(SettingsProvider.java:1516)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:495)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.call(ContentProvider.java:2511)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:525)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.putForUser(SettingsService.java:384)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService$MyShellCommand.onCommand(SettingsService.java:280)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsService.onShellCommand(SettingsService.java:51)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1073)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:901)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1331)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1268)
$ ~/w/own [255]>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Alright, that confirms it. My solution in the meantime has been LineageOS 20.0, which was release just before 2023. It supports the native per-app-language which works well one you disable the opt-in setting.

Answer (score 0):

just attempt to delete the setting and create it afterwards.

delete settings:

```
adb shell settings delete global settings_app_locale_opt_in_enabled                                                                       
Deleted 0 rows
```

create it and assign the value:

```
adb shell settings put global settings_app_locale_opt_in_enabled false
```

confirm it's in place:

```
adb shell settings get global settings_app_locale_opt_in_enabled                                                                                
false
```